# Is `completion` block of `UIViewController.present` guaranteed to be running on main thread?

Tags: swift, multithreading

Seems a simple question, but I don't see any definitive answer.

In `UIViewController` function:

```
func present(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, 
             animated flag: Bool, 
             completion: (() -> Void)? = nil)
```

Is `completion` block guaranteed to be running on main thread?

In other words. Can I do this:

```
vc.present(anotherVC, animated: animated) { [weak self] in

        guard let self = self else { return }

        // do some UI operations
        self.<...>
}
```

Or should I do this:

```
vc.present(anotherVC, animated: animated) { 

        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in

            guard let self = self else { return }

            // do some UI operations
            self.<...>
        }
}
```

Note: I tried to test it a bunch of times, and seems it's always running on main thread. But that could be by accident, and Apple's doc doesn't say anything explicit.

Answer (score 0):

The completion callback runs on the main thread. There is no reason otherwise since  all UI-related manipulations by cocoa are done on the main thread. However you should be calling the `present` function from the main thread as well.